# System font of different sizes that respect Dynamic Type

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

There are 2 ways I can find to generate `Dynamic Type`-sensitive sizing.

1. System fonts

```
.font(.system(.title))
```

2. Custom fonts

```
.font(.custom("AmericanTypewriter", size: 22, relativeTo: .title))
```

But let's say I want to use a system font that respects Dynamic type.

When I do something like this:

```
.font(.system(size: 28, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
```

all Dynamic Type is lost.

How can I specify system fonts of a specific size, but let it scale with Dynamic Type?

Comment: You can likely use ScaledMetric for the size

Comment: Kudos for bringing that up. Some folk would just take the dynamic type that comes for free in swiftui and happily flush that down the toilet without thinking just because Figmat or whaever told it so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the scaled size:

```
let scaledSize = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledValue(for: 28)
```

and then use that to set your font size:

```
.font(.system(size: scaledSize, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
```

You can replace `.body` in the UIFontMetrics initializer with any other `UIFont.TextStyle`